# How can I form multiple lists from append

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I made this code in order that every time it runs once it gives me a list in the correct sequence, I wanted the code to form a list from the repetition forming p1+p2+p3, but the code gives me all the p1 plus all the p2 plus all the p3, I wish every time it ran I was given a list.

```
p11 = []
p22 = []
p33 = []
for n in range(0, quantidade):
  print('EPISÓDIO', n+1)
  for g in range(0, prot):
   p1 = ' ' + protagonistasn[g] + ' ' + random.choice(açoes) + ' ' + random.choice(coadjuvantesn) + ' ' + random.choice(locais)
   if g <= prot/2 :
    p1_1 = p1.replace("@","a")
    p11.append(p1_1)
    print(p1_1)
   elif g > prot/2 :
    p1_1 = p1.replace("@", "o")
    p11.append(p1_1)
    print(p1_1)
  for j in range(0, vil):
   p2 = ' ' +viloesn[j]+ ' ' + random.choice(açoes) + ' ' + random.choice(protagonistasn) + ' ' + random.choice(locais)
   if j <= vil/2:
    p2_2 = p2.replace("@", "a")
    p22.append(p2_2)
    print(p2_2)
   elif j > vil/2:
    p2_2 = p2.replace("@", "o")
    p22.append(p2_2)
    print(p2_2)
  for h in range(0, prot):
   p3 = ' ' + protagonistasn[h] + ' ' + random.choice(açoes) + ' ' + random.choice(viloesn) + ' ' + random.choice(locais)
   if h <= prot/2 :
    p3_3 = p3.replace("@","a")
    p33.append(p3_3)
    print(p3_3)
   elif h > prot/2 :
    p3_3 = p3.replace("@", "o")
    p33.append(p3_3)
    print(p3_3)
p_total = [p11, p22, p33]
p_tot = []
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `n` in your loop, so naturally you are going to produce `quantidade` identical results.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: The n is accurate because I need this code to run several times, because each time it runs something different comes out

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want your `p_total` list to contain all the p1s, p2s, and p3s from the first iteration, and then all the p1s, p2s, and p3d from the second iteration.  Is that right?  If so:

```
p_total = []
for n in range(0, quantidade):
  p11 = []
  p22 = []
  p33 = []
  print('EPIS?DIO', n+1)
  for g in range(0, prot):
...
    print(p3_3)
  p_total.extend( [p11, p22, p33] )
p_tot = []
```

So, start each loop with an empty p11, p22, and p33.  At the end of each iteration, append those on to your `p_total`, instead of holding them until the end.

Comment: that's what i need